# Process for developing new version of site and publishing at once

Tags: sharepoint-server

It has been a handful of years since I've last used SharePoint and the last version I used was 2007, so I'm quite bit rusty on aspects.

What is the process if you want to make significant changes to an existing site and publish all of those changes at once? Essentially: how would one go about doing significant site editing without interrupting a live site?

I'm using SharePoint 2013.